# What is the word pronounced in this video?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, spelling

I'm curious about the words pronounced at 0:46 - 0:48 exactly 
[in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=46&v=BQVQfrIh9Qc):

> If you add a lot of metatags to a page, it XXX you

What are the XXX words ?

I can understand that it means like "causing harm".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you added a lot of meta tags to a page, it could **count against you** because of all the redundant code that some of the engines wouldn't use.